# Prove: Let $a,b\in R$ such that $a\lt b$, and $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ be monotonic, then $\frac{1}{f}$ is also monotonic

Tags: calculus, soft-question, monotone-functions

**Prove or disprove**: Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be monotone. 
If $f(x)\ne 0$ for all [a,b], then $1/f$ is also monotone on [a,b].

I've been sitting on this for quite a while trying to find a function to disprove this.

If $x\le y$, then $f(x) \le f(y)$ (increasing) or $f(x)\ge f(y)$ (decreasing).

**Soft-Question** I need to either prove for all functions, or give one example where this is false. When given questions like this, what's the approach/ process when trying to prove/disprove?  I tried approaching it by testing various elementary functions (square root, linear,polynomials, trig functions) but nothing has come up, meaning it has to be some sort of combination function, but I'm still having difficulties.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ should disprove it.

Comment: $1/x$ is monotone away from $x=0$, where $1/x$ is undefined.

Comment: @KennyLau $f(x)\ne 0$, so then $\frac{1}{x}$ is an example that $\frac{1}{f} $is mono

Comment: Why do you want to disprove it?

Comment: @awllower this is a review question. I need to prove for all functions, or give one contradictory example

Comment: @RonaldB Even if you only consider the positive and negative number, $\dfrac1x$ still is not monotonic.

Comment: $(1/x)^\prime=-1/x^2$ so $x\mapsto 1/x$ is monotone on $(0, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: But not on $\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: But the question asks for monotonicity on an interval, and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is not an interval (not connected).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe a counter-example
(check) is $$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \text{if }x<0;\\
x+1 & \text{if }x\geq0.
\end{cases}
$$
You can take your interval to be $[-1,1]$, but anything including zero suffices.

---

As for your soft question, my thought process was as follows: I proved it for continuous functions, then I noticed that it seemed "too good to be true" for any function. I also noticed that the discontinuity should "avoid" the value zero on the $y$-axis, so I tried to think of a function with a single simple discontinuity.

Comment: I won't be able to get examples from others come exam time. I was really looking for a "thought process" that I should have when it comes to questions like this. I just thought of f(x) =x-2 when [1,2) and x when [2,3]

Comment: How is it that you came up with [the exact function I just posted 9 minutes ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30631582#30631582) without ever going to chat?

Comment: I'm psychic? ;)
Or maybe great minds think alike?

Comment: Continuity is only needed to guarantee that $f$ doesn't change sign.

Comment: Ah, you are indeed correct. Editing.

Comment: @par thank you for answering my question. That is what I needed.

Comment: @RonaldB: if mine or N.S.'s answer is satisfactory, please consider accepting one of them.

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x) \leq f(y)$ dividing both sides by $f(x) f(y)$ we get 
$$\frac{1}{f(x)} \geq \frac{1}{f(y)} \mbox{ whenever } f(x) f(y) > 0 \\
\frac{1}{f(x)} \leq \frac{1}{f(y)} \mbox{ whenever } f(x) f(y) < 0 $$

This tells you that $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is monotonic exactly when $f(x) f(y)$ doesn't change sign (and it is easy to see that this happens exactly when this is always positive, meaning that $f(x)$ doesn't change sign).

Conclusion:

- If $f(x)$ doesn't change sign the claim is true.
- If $f(x)$ changes sign the claim is false.

Comment: I liked this answer a lot. If only I could come up with ideas like this alone.